# How are NULL DACL and empty DACL treated?

Tags: windows, security, information-theory, dacl

I don't find any information about how are the special case NULL DACL and empty DACL treated in Windows.

I understand what they are but don't know how they are treated..

Answer (score 1):

[Null DACLs and Empty DACLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/null-dacls-and-empty-dacls)

> A null DACL grants full access to any user that requests it; normal security checking is not performed with respect to the object. ... An empty DACL grants no access to the object it is assigned to.

Another way to think of it, an empty list is not really special at all but because it is empty it has no ACLs that can grant anything.

On the other hand, a NULL DACL granting access is a design decision made by the Windows developers.